# Serial Port stops transferring data once the matplotlib graph opens

Tags: python, matplotlib, serialization

Using pyserial, I am trying to get data through serial Port (in Ubuntu) and trying to plot it in real time using Matplotlib.  (All happening in Tkinter GUI).

Data is getting transferred perfectly but the moment when matplotlib window opens up (plt.show()), Serial Port Data transfer stops. (doesn't resume).

Even I tried to use different threads for serial port and Matplotlib. but Tkinter is not allowing.

It says : " RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop".

Any idea whats happening here. Thanks.

Comment: All we can say is that the "main thread is not [running] in [the] main loop", just as the error suggests. There are a lot of examples out there which use pyserial to plot a matplotlib graph. For help, look through them and share a [mcve] of the issue.

Comment: lets forget about threading here. Still why does serial data transfer stops once the matplotlib window opens ?

Comment: What I'm saying is that there are enough examples around where it does not stop. In order to find out why it stops *in your case* , one would need to know *your case*, but you keep it secret. Provide a [mcve] of the issue and then you have the chance of obtaining an answer here.

Comment: I got it solved.  @ImportanceOfBeingErnest , in future I won't forget to provide a code snippet for better understanding of the given problem. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import time  
import serial  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

def livePlotting(COM):  
    startTime = time.time()  
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 4), dpi=100)
    axes = plt.subplot(2, 2, 1)
    axes.set_xlim(0, 130)
    axes.set_ylim(-2, 2)

    x_datapoints = []
    y_datapoints = []
    line, = axes.plot(x_datapoints, y_datapoints, 'b-')

    ser = serial.Serial(COM, 9600)
    counter = 0
    while True:
        data = ser.readline()
        valuesToPlot = data.split(',')

        print "Live Plotting Now......."
        if counter <=1000:      # Just an ex., if we want only 1000 datapoints to get plotted.
            x_datapoints.append(counter)
            y_datapoints.append(valuesToPlot[0])

            line.set_xdata(x_datapoints)
            line.set_ydata(y_datapoints)

            plt.draw()
            plt.pause(1e-20)
            time.sleep(0.2)
            counter +=1
    print "Time taken in plotting :", time.time() - startTime        
    plt.show()   

if __name__ == "__main__":
    COMport = '/dev/ttyACM1'
    livePlotting(COMport)
```

Comment: I got it worked. JUst for a better understanding of the problem, I have provided a sample code here. Thanks.